# Stop form submitting in jquery if an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Xk38X/6/

```
  $('#register').click(function()
{
    if( $('#company_f').val().length == 0 ) {
        $('#company_f').css("border", "solid 1px red");
    }
});
```

The issue is even when it errors it still sends the form. Can anyone please tell me how I stop it submitting the form if the user hits the button and the company field isn't filled out.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider separating the fact that there is an error from how that error is handled, and particularly the precise presentation details of the error.

Comment: You should be using a `<form>` to group your inputs and a `submit()` event for the submission of that form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `return false` or [event.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$('#register').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#company_f').val().length == 0) {
        $('#company_f').css("border", "solid 1px red");
        return false; // or e.preventdefault();
    }
});
```

---

A Little better version of your code

```
var company_f = $('#company_f'); //cache your selector
$('#register').click(function (e) {
    if (company_f.val().length == 0) {
        company_f.css("border", "solid 1px red");
        return false; // or e.preventdefault();
    }
});
```

---

Also Read [HTML required attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute)

Comment: Typically, when using `e.preventDefault()`, it's the _first_ line within the event handler function, as opposed by `return false`, which is the _last_.  See the code example posted in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way:

```
 $('#register').click(function(event)
   {
if( $('#company_f').val().length == 0 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#company_f').css("border", "solid 1px red");

    }
   });
```

Comment: Typically, when using `e.preventDefault()`, it's the _first_ line within the event handler function, as opposed by `return false`, which is the _last_.  See the code example posted in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).