# appned form validation message below and remove on select

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to validate a form: here is my form:

```
<p id="billing_first_name_field" class="form-row form-row form-row-wide validate-required"><label class="" for="billing_first_name">Name <abbr title="required" class="required">*</abbr></label><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Name or Nickname" id="billing_first_name" name="billing_first_name" class="input-text "></p>


<p id="billing_phone_field" class="form-row form-row form-row-last validate-required validate-phone woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field"><label class="" for="billing_phone">Phone <abbr title="required" class="required">*</abbr></label><input type="tel" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number" id="billing_phone" name="billing_phone" class="input-text "><div class="notification-box error form_checkout"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Please Enter Valid Mobile Number</div></p>


$('#billing_first_name').click(function() {
    //console.log("cl")
        $('.login-right').remove('notification-box');

});
$('#billing_first_name').on('focusout', function() {
        if( validate_input($(this).val()))
    { 
        $(this).after( "<div class='notification-box error form_checkout'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Please Enter Your First Name</div>" );
    }
```

});

```
var reg = /^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$/;

 $('#billing_phone').on('focusout', function() {
  if (!reg.test($(this).val()))
    { 
        $(this).after( "<div class='notification-box error form_checkout'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>Please Enter Valid Mobile Number</div>" );
    }
});
```

also when I am trying to remove that notice box i used this:

```
$(".input-text").click(function() {

$('.notification-box').fadeOut('slow');
```

});

now my problem is if I click any of the input all mesages got removed i just one removed the current selected textbox message. also i want tp prevent the form being submit until validate for name it prevents but for phone of one digit is place the form can be submitted.

how to remove the duplicate after message?
how to remove selected text box message?
how to prevent submit for phone too?

Comment: `$(this).find('.notification-box').fadeOut('slow');` ?

Answer (score 0):

`.after()` adds the element after matched selector, which makes added element as immediate next sibling.You need to use `.next()` along with input type element context in click event:

```
$(".input-text").click(function() {
  $(this).next().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks its working perfectly, just 1 q how to prevent submit until phone is validated? this is a wooommerce form so its just preventing until any digit is placed, i want to validate as per my rule then submit

Comment: @DipannitaChoudhury: you can do something similar like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21815176/1719752.  check the length of visible  `.notification-box` element. if greater than 0, return false in submit event.